How to check if a user fill a Editext using AutoFill in android?
I want to check if a user enters the text on EditText using Android AutoFill hints that appear above the keyboard. I want to know if there is a listener available in Android Framework through which we can detect if a user filled the Editext using AutoFill hints and manipulate the text that is coming from Autofill hint.

Implement an onFocusChangeListener on your EditText and check if the EditText is empty before the focus change and has text after the focus change.

To detect if a user filled the EditText using Autofill hints in Android and to manipulate the text, you can use the AutofillManager along with a TextWatcher. The AutofillManager provides callbacks to notify when the autofill event occurs. Here's how you can achieve this:
Enable Autofill for EditText: Ensure that your EditText is configured to support autofill by setting appropriate autofill hints.
Use AutofillManager: Register an AutofillCallback to detect autofill events.
TextWatcher: Use a TextWatcher to manipulate the text when it changes. Inside onTextChanged, if the text length exceeds 8 characters, truncate it to 8 characters and set it back to the EditText.
in your xml file:
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="username"
    android:hint="Enter your username" />

In your Activity or Fragment, use AutofillManager to register an AutofillCallback and a TextWatcher to manipulate the text:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.service.autofill.AutofillCallback
import android.view.autofill.AutofillManager
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var autofillManager: AutofillManager
private lateinit var myEditText: EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    myEditText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text)
    autofillManager = getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)

    autofillManager?.registerCallback(object : AutofillCallback() {
        override fun onAutofillEvent(view: View, event: Int) {
            super.onAutofillEvent(view, event)
            if (event == AutofillCallback.EVENT_INPUT_SHOWN ||
                event == AutofillCallback.EVENT_INPUT_HIDDEN ||
                event == AutofillCallback.EVENT_INPUT_UNAVAILABLE) {
                // Autofill event detected
                val text = myEditText.text.toString()
                if (text.length > 8) {
                    // Manipulate text if length is greater than 8
                    myEditText.setText(text.substring(0, 8))
                    myEditText.setSelection(8) // Move cursor to the end
                }
            }
        }
    })

    // Add TextWatcher to EditText
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            s?.let {
                if (it.length > 8) {
                    myEditText.setText(it.substring(0, 8))
                    myEditText.setSelection(8) // Move cursor to the end
                }
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    })
}
}

